# Sort by word position (word index) in a sentence using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Is this possible to select sentences by their position (index) of matching word in SQL?

I mean a select query like this:

- Find sentences that match search pattern at the beginning of the
  first word
- Find sentences that match search pattern at the beginning
  of second word
- Find sentences that match search pattern at the
  beginning of third word
- Find sentences that match search pattern in
  any other place in the sentence.

If so any examples are welcome.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `position()` and `order by` to come close to what you want

```
order by position(' ' || @search_pattern, ' ' || sentence)
```

If you want to filter the data, you can split the sentence into words and look at each of them:

```
select *
from (values ('a abc def asdfdsf.   kljkj')) v(sentence) cross join lateral
     regexp_split_to_array(sentence, '[^\w]+') words
where words[1] like @pattern || '%' or
      words[2] like @pattern || '%' or
      words[3] like @pattern || '%' or
      sentence like @pattern || '%'
```

Comment: How can I sort there results alphabetically?

Comment: @MarekMarczak . . . You would add `order by sentence`.

Comment: I mean this: First word match and then alphabetically, second word match and then alphabetically, thirtd word match and then alphabetically. The rest and alphabetically. If I add `order by sentence` results are sorted alphabetically in whole, not by their position and then alphabetically.

Comment: I think I could split the sentence into 4 columns, make queries, sort them alphabetically (separately) and use `union` but I think it won't be very performant solution. Do you have and ideas how to achieve the result in a more suitable way?

Comment: Actually I've just tested my solution and sentences were sorted alphabetically in whole too. I don't know how to preserve position order and sort alphabetically within the limits of the order.

Comment: @MarekMarczak . . . Perhaps you should ask a new question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using Postgres' regex like capabilities.  For example to find a pattern at the beginning of the second word, you could use:

```
select *
from your_table
where sentence ~ '^\w+\s+\ypattern';
```

In general, to find a pattern at the beginning of the Nth word, you may use:

```
select *
from your_table
where sentence ~ '^(?:\w+\s+){n-1}\ypattern';
```

### Demo